# Unknown value in the modular numerator

Tags: modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

I'm looking for a mathematical solution to find unknown value in the numerator as follows:

IF:  $$b_1 + b_2 = 151$$
$$n = 86167$$

$$ (231 * 336 + b_1)^2 \mod 86167 = 151^2 $$
$$ (25 * 336 + b_2)^2 \mod 86167 = 151^2 $$

So, How can I find $b_1$ and $b_2$ mathematically ??

Comment: What part of this is given, and what part represents your attempt at solving the problem?  I also don't know what the term "modular numerator" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @EricLee $22801>86167?$

Comment: Are you allowed to use that $86167=199\cdot 433?$ That lets you solve $231\cdot 336 b_1\equiv \pm 151 \pmod{199}$ and $231\cdot 336 b_1\equiv\pm 151\pmod{433}$ then solve for four values $b_1$ modulo $86167$ by Chinese remainder theorem. Then similar for $25\cdot 336 b_2\equiv \pm 151\pmod{199,433}$

Comment: Is the goal to factor the modulus, or are you know and can use its factorization?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  : Thanks alot for your answer, I was trying to study if this equation will guide me for fast factorization method.

Comment: @BillDubuque : It's just a small study to find a fast factorization method.

Comment: Are you already familiar with existing factorization algorithms that work by finding nontrivial modular square roots, e.g. [quadratic sieves?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve)  If so, what is your idea for improvement?

Comment: Not yet sir, I still learn and learn in this subject. My idea in this question is to take the reminder of $n mod 256$ and you will get $quotient∗256+reminder=n$
, after that I tried to find all the values that congruence with $reminder^2 (mod n)$. At this point I found the quotient is constant with the congruence values and the step to find the solution is to find a small value in the range (1,256) + a value in the reminder range(1,reminder) or range (1, reminder+quotient). I hope that my explanation was clear. Thanks